# Try-Catch Exception abuse

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have found some code like this:

```
try 
{
    myClass.do().ToString();
} catch () { }
```

which certainly results in an exception being thrown when `do()` returns `null`.  You could, instead, use

```
(myClass.do() ?? "").ToString();
```

to avoid the exception being thrown.  I also see code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    if (x.Phases[i].num == activeNum)
    {
        try
        {
           result = x.Phases[i + 1].obj;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {  }
    }
}
```

I think that this is not good practice. However, I can't find any references to support my ideas.

I tried to search on web, but I did not have any luck. Most of the references or documentation was meant for C++ or Java.

Will you please help me to justify my idea with strong reference, or enlighten me if the previous approaches above are in fact acceptable.

Comment: " However, I cant find any reference to support my ideas" - please try searching harder....

Comment: JK: agree with @Rob.. let us be more lenient to language's mistake - unless the post is written in non-English at all.

Comment: @Mitch, yes i do found thousands of reference. but most of it wasn't concise enough to give the specific idea i am looking for. Should I waste my time diving into each article, or should I asked someone who has exceptional experienced and ideas so that i may focused on my own task?

Comment: The whole `try`/`catch` like that is a bad anti-pattern. Have a read of [Eric Lippert's Vexing Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct: using exceptions for purposes of flow control is generally bad practice.  It is often referred to as an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) for this reason.

You can find a detailed explanation [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl).  While the article references Java and C++, it is also an anti-pattern in C# for much the same reasons.

For a C#/.Net specific explanation, see this [MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chris.green/2008/02/10/dont-use-exceptions-to-control-application-flow/).

Comment: Perfect. The only thing I would add to your answer is to summarize those references by starting your post with something like "You are correct that using exceptions to create a flow of control is a bad idea". You have my upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I am still trying to get the whole answer authorship thing down :-)

Comment: @AGB - Please don't write "link-only" answers. You should only add links to support the content that you have already put in your answer. Stack Overflow answers shouldn't rely on other site's links not ever becoming broken.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right.  Exception handling is slow.

Branching (such as an underlying jump when the for-loop terminates) is very fast.

Don't waste your time on exception handling as a means of flow control.

EDIT:
Note that there is ample evidence for such claims, and that for instance, you may reference [the Wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) for an explicit indication that flow control is not the intended role of exception handling code in C#.

Comment: You happen to be right, but answers like this should have sources. I wasn't the one who downvoted though.

Comment: I would note that the question does not exclusively ask for references but also for an affirmative response with respect to the correctness of the alternative approach.  I disconfirmed that particular approach and in the spirit of @Mitch's comment I declined to "Google it for" the OP.

Comment: I'm not going to get into a protracted argument here, so this is the last I will post. First of all, for this type of question you should always provide references because your opinion that one method is better than the other is irrelevant without any proof. Second, he asked "please help me to justify my idea with strong reference, or enlighten me if the previous approach just like above was acceptable." You did neither. You did not justify that the approach in question was acceptable, and you did not justify his idea with a reference. He did, as you put it, "exclusively ask" for references.

Comment: fast / slow with exceptions can be neglectable, depending on when / what and how critical is that piece of code.

Comment: @auto_increment, i accidentally hit up-vote. But I hope you could provide a reference to support your statement. Thanks. ^_^